# How to keep playing audio when clicking back button iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, audio

I'm developing a radio streaming app with XCode 4.5 for iOS 6 and mainly using storyboards. After the login view,it will display a tab bar controller which consists of 3 tabs: Channel List, About, News. It opens the Channel List tab as default after logged in which is showing a list of radio channels (i'm using uitableview to populate the list). Then clicking one channel will bring you to another view controller (in the same tab menu) showing the Now Playing view in which you need to tap the play button to start the streamer.

Here I'm implementing Matt Gallagher's audio streamer. I already added the 'Required background modes' key and the value 'App plays audio' on my Info.plist. I also added below code in my appDelegate's didFinishLaunchinWithOptions: method

```
UIDevice *thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
if([thisDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]
   && thisDevice.multitaskingSupported)
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        /* just fail if this happens. */
        NSLog(@"BackgroundTask Expiration Handler is called");
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
    }];
}
```

So far I run it in my simulator, after selecting one of the channels, and tap the play button in the Now Playing view, it still play the audio even if I move to the About or News tab. It also has no problems when I click Home.
My problem is, when I click the navigation bar's Back Button above the Now Playing view (means going back to the Channel list), or when I click the most upper back button (means going back to the login view) the audio stops playing. And when I tried to open the same channel, it doesn't resume the streaming and I need to click the play button to start again.

How can I make it so that as long as user is logged in,when navigating back to the channel list or to the login view the audio keeps playing (unless user clicks different channel)?
I'm guessing this has something to do with the UITableView, like keeping the state of selected cell. But I dunno how to do that. So please, I appreciate your helps :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code you showed. If the playing stops, it is presumably because when you go back and the view controller goes out of existence, the player goes out of existence with it. You've put your player in the wrong place, that's all. It needs to be in the app delegate so that it can always persist.

Comment: @matt I followed your suggestion and edited my question,please check :)

Comment: Do not alter your question to ask a completely unrelated question. I answered the question you asked and my answer seems to have helped. For a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: @matt okay, I'm sorry. I myself just realized that. Thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I followed @matt 's suggestion about putting the audio streamer into the appDelegate. I moved the below code from Now Playing view controller to my appDelegate.m file

```
#pragma mark - audio streamer

- (void)playAudio:(indoRadio *)np withButton:(NSString *)currentButton
{
    if ([currentButton isEqual:@"playbutton.png"])
    {
        [self.nowplayingVC.downloadSourceField resignFirstResponder];

        [self createStreamer:np.URL];
        [self.nowplayingVC setButtonImageNamed:@"loadingbutton.png"];
        [audioStreamer start];
    }
    else
    {
        [audioStreamer stop];
    }
}

- (void)createStreamer:(NSString *)url
{
    if (audioStreamer)
    {
        return;
    }

    [self destroyStreamer];

    NSString *escapedValue = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil,(CFStringRef)url,NULL,NULL,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    NSURL *streamurl = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedValue];
    audioStreamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:streamurl];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged:)
     name:ASStatusChangedNotification
     object:audioStreamer];
}

- (void)playbackStateChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if ([audioStreamer isWaiting])
    {
        [self.radioDetailVC setButtonImageNamed:@"loadingbutton.png"];
    }
    else if ([audioStreamer isPlaying])
    {
        [self.nowplayingVC setButtonImageNamed:@"stopbutton.png"];
    }
    else if ([audioStreamer isIdle])
    {
        [self destroyStreamer];
        [self.nowplayingVC setButtonImageNamed:@"playbutton.png"];
    }
}

- (void)destroyStreamer
{
    if (audioStreamer)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         removeObserver:self
         name:ASStatusChangedNotification
         object:audioStreamer];

        [audioStreamer stop];
        audioStreamer = nil;
    }
}
```

When I click the play button, the audio streamer works well in background. Wherever I go both inside and outside the app,it's still playing.